# What's the meaning of the S symbol in Repository Registry

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

At my internship we use an [older version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8sj3.png) (TortoiseHG version 2.1.3 with Mercurial 1.9.2) of Mercurial and TortoiseHG. In the [Repository Registry of TortoiseHG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Prfkr.png) I've noticed these two Icons:

- [image: The normal Mercurial icon] The normal Mercurial icon
- [image: The Mercurial icon with an S symbol] The Mercurial icon with an S symbol

The [image: Mercurial icon with an S symbol] doesn't seem to make any difference to the repository and seems to pop up at random. After searching online and trough the docs, I couldn't find the meaning behind this symbol.

So my question is: What does [image: The Mercurial icon with an S symbol] mean and what does it do different from [image: The normal Mercurial icon]?

Comment: You're running extremely old versions of TortoiseHG and mercurial.

Comment: @ngoldbaum Yes, I know. The people at my internship told me to install this version. I don't know why they use this version and never really bothered to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

those icons mean subrepository as you can see on these pages:

- [old subrepo tutorial part-1](http://www.swiftsoftwaregroup.com/hg-subrepositories-a-how-to-guide-for-the-svnexternals-junkie-part-1)
- [old subrepo tutorial part-2](http://www.swiftsoftwaregroup.com/hg-subrepositories-a-how-to-guide-for-the-svnexternals-junkie-part-2)

e.g. screenshot [image: old workbench with subrepositories]

Comment: That seems to be the case, yes. Although it doesn't show it exactly like in the screenshot, all the repositories with an S are part of a parent repository.

Comment: it would be difficult to guess why is the difference, but it could be a different version. There was a lot of changes after v2.1.3 involving "subrepos" as you can check out here https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/wiki/OlderReleaseNotes